# How to use GAE Appstats to monitor the task that is running in task queue?

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine

I have a use case where I need to monitor the number of datastore operations and also the time consumed by a particular block of Java code that is running in the task queue.

As of now, I am using Appstats and it is not displaying the operations performed by the task (Java Code) that is running in the Task Queue. Also, I need to know the execution time of particular code blocks in the same code in the task queue by using some kind of monitors.

Please suggest and advise if I could use some other tools for the above requirement.

Comment: Where are you looking for those operations? You should be looking at the request (handler) for the URL specified at task enqueuing, not at the request (handler) which creates and enqueues the task - they are separate requests with separate appstats info.

Comment: Thanks... is there any way that I can view these separate appstats info, do I have to make any changes in web.xml in the servlet mapping of the appstats?

Comment: Changes may be necessary if your task queue handler runs in a  service different than the one enqueueing the task. The appstats documentation applies to single-service apps, for multi-service apps each service is independently configured for appstats.

Comment: Thanks, to make it more clear, I am adding some more information: I need to perform large insert operations from an App Engine Application to Datastore, as of now, the speed of insertion is around 80 rows per minute for a data containing 11 columns and 80000 rows. This speed seems to be very low and I need 80rows per sec instead of per minute.

Comment: I had searched about batch operations, but still I am not getting considerable improvement if I create batches of 50 rows and if I add more rows in a batch the operations are not successful. Therefore, I needed a mechanism by which I can monitor which block of code takes more time. I tried integrating Jamon, but was unable to execute because of jsp errors while deploying. Is there any tool from Google that would help to monitor the time taken by the block of code in App Engine.